# Integration Convergence/Divergence Questtion

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int\limits_0^{\pi} \frac{ dt}{\sqrt{t} + \sin t }$$
How can one tell if this integral converges or diverges?
Integral of $1/(\sqrt{t}+\sin(t))$ from $0$ to $\pi$.
I can't even find the antiderivative.

Comment: Don't look for antiderivative; look for a similar, but simpler integral to compare to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...**Hint**: $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}+\sin t} \leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$

Comment: I thought the comparison test only works when the bounds are from [0,infinity). @back2basic